# Google Search quotes do not work for non-English text

Tags: google-search, search-engine

If it's an English text ([eg](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=%22tester%22%20%E8%87%AA%E6%9C%89%E9%81%93%E7%90%86%20%E9%A6%99%E8%95%89%E8%9A%82%E8%9A%81&num=100)), all search results will have the quoted text.

But otherwise ([eg](https://encrypted.google.com/search?num=100&q=%22%E5%9B%A0%E4%B8%BA%E6%89%80%E4%BB%A5%22%20%E8%87%AA%E6%9C%89%E9%81%93%E7%90%86%20%E9%A6%99%E8%95%89%E8%9A%82%E8%9A%81) (ctrl-F ≪因为≫)) no.

Why does it not work? How to get it to work?

Comment: Quoted English text doesn't always work literally. Despite quoting, the text is sometime split in the results, and this may be happening in your ≪sample 2≫. Possibly also, if the algorithm is none too clever, the byte sequences used to represent the Chinese characters are themselves being split, resulting in complete mismatches. These are pure guesses, as I've never needed to work with such languages, but I do know how coders think.

Comment: @AFH, Split is proper behavior (If it's not already obvious, double quotes in Google mean "**show everything** that is within the quotes, without exceptions, in that *order*". It's about the *order* and ain't nothing to do with splits) ; Ctrl F that on sample-2's: **it doesn't show**.

Comment: @AFH, (A separate use of quotes for english-able text is to prevent Google from adding spaces between words. Eg https://www.google.com/search?q=assignour and https://www.google.com/search?q="assignour"

Comment: Thanks for those examples. I think the treatment of quotes must have changed. I used to use them in order to make Google interpret punctuation literally, including spaces, but you have certainly shown that it is no longer so, and punctuation characters are now just treated as delimiters, whether within quotes or not.